# How to get next message in a for loop via python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

My question was how to get a text from next message from user in a for loop, there's a example of my code below:

```
async def end(update: Update, contex: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.callback_query.edit_message_reply_markup(reply_markup=None)

    callback_data = update.callback_query.data.split(sep=',')
    subsystem = callback_data[0]
    env = callback_data[1]

    gc = GoogleSheetsUpdater().connect()

    sheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + config['DEFAULT']['spreadsheetId']

    sheet = gc.open_by_url(sheet_url)

    ws = sheet.get_worksheet(0)

    df = pandas.DataFrame(ws.get_all_records())

    apps_list = df['app'][df['subsystem'] == subsystem]

    for app in apps_list:

        tag_text = f"Please, send me a tag fro {app} in {subsystem}:"

        await update.callback_query.edit_message_text(text=tag_text)

        time.sleep(10)

        # I cant get a tag from next user message here
        async def tag_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):

            tag = update.message.text

            print(tag)

            return
```

And I don't know why this is not working properly...
My suggestion is to place a new MessageHandler like this:

```
        @Application.add_handler(handler=MessageHandler(filters=filters.Text, callback=Update))
        async def tag_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):

            tag = update.message.text

            print(tag)

            return
```

But it's not working either.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In `python-telegram-bot`, a handler callback function always handles one update at a time. No more, no less. It is not possible to wait for the next update from within the handler callback function.
To do that, PTB comes with the [`ConversationHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html#telegram.ext.ConversationHandler).

Moreover, `@Application.add_handler` is not a syntax that is supported by `python-telegram-bot`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.